# How do I  maintain a portable induction cooker?

Tags: induction

Most portable induction cooker have a cooling system (a fan below it). Do you open up the induction cooker to clean the fan? As for the rest of the parts, do you just use a cloth to wipe clean? or do you apply some cleaning agent to wash the outer surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper surface is glass, so I clean it like a normal Ceran stove: A special ceran cleaner when a cloth isn't enough, a sharp blade for specks, a gentle abrasive (like Cif) for stubborn spots which won't get away. The sides of mine are alu, but I don't bother getting out a different cleaning agent for that, just continue wiping with whatever I used on the glass.

I have never opened mine to clean the fan, and suspect that it will void the warranty. But if needed, I would handle it like a PC fan: open the case, use compressed air to blow it clean. Trying to wipe the fan could decenter it. It won't make the blades perfectly smooth, as the humid kitchen air tends to turn dust to clingy grime, but it should remove the bulk if the fan is too full to work efficiently.

Comment: Thanks rumtscho, I almost open mime to clean the fan but I think it would be better as you had advise - use compressed air.